# Node.js buffer string serialization

Tags: node.js

I want to serialize a buffer to string without any overhead ( one character for one byte) and be able to unserialize it into buffer again.

```
var b = new Buffer (4) ;
var s = b.toString() ;
var b2 = new Buffer (s)
```

Produces the same results only for values below 128. I want to use the whole scope of 0-255.

I know I can write it in a loop with String.fromCharCode() in serializing and String.charCodeAt() in deserializing, but I'm looking for some native module implementation if there is any.

Comment: There is deprecated `binary` encoding. But I would suggest to use `base64` encoding

Comment: @AlexeyTen that is the right answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `'latin1'` encoding, but you should generally try to avoid it because converting  a Buffer to a binary string has some extra computational overhead.

Example:

```
var b = Buffer.alloc(4);
var s = b.toString('latin1');
var b2 = Buffer.from(s, 'latin1');
```

Comment: The answer seems to be outdated now. node.js prints`DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.` `new Buffer(s, 'binary')` should be replaced with `Buffer.from(s, 'binary')`. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/buffer-constructor-deprecation/#variant-1:~:text=What%20you%20would%20do%20in%20this%20case%20is